# How to iteratively call an api, write results to multiple CSVs, and combine them into one csv using pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, api, csv

I have a CSV file with one column, 'content'. I need to score each row for a specific value. I am limited to 250 records at once, but my file contains many many thousands of records.

How do I appropriately chunk this data so my finished result will be a single CSV file with all N rows scored and filtered?

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
import csv

# endpoint
url = 'url'
# authorization
api_key = 'key'
# score threshold
threshold = 0.5
# source data file
input_data = 'file'
# output (filtered) data file
output_data = 'file'


# read in data from csv
data = pd.read_csv(input_data)
content = data['content'].tolist()[0:250]  # take small batches since the model has limited RAM
# construct json request body
records = []
for i, text in enumerate(content):
    records.append({'id': str(i), 'content': text})
records = {'records': records}
records = json.dumps(records)
# send request and get response
response = requests.post(url, data=records, headers={'x-api-key': api_key})
# pull out predictions
output = response.json()['body']['predictions']
# filter results to records that have high enough 'value' score and write them out
with open(output_data, 'w', newline='') as file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for obj in output:
        record_id = int(obj['id'])
        score = obj['distribution']['scores']['value']
        if score > threshold:
            csv_writer.writerow([content[record_id]])
```

Comment: @gold_cy No, it doesn't! CodeReview deals with complete and working code, and doesn't answer "how to" questions.

Comment: this code works, it just needs to be broken in to functions

Comment: If someone could direct me to the appropriate channel for help with that it would be greatly appreciated